# Akka Receive Method case mutable.Map gives a runtime error

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm trying to run the `receive method` of `Akka Actor` in the following way:

```
  def receive = {
    case  x: collection.mutable.Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String,Float]]=>
    insertValueIntoTable(x)
  }
```

I'm able to compile this with no issues, but I get the error:

> Error:(83, 57) ']' expected but '.' found.
>         case  x: collection.mutable.Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String,Float]]=>

Is there any other way I can pass a `mutable map` which has a `value` as another `mutable map`? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actor communication with mutable messages is a bad idea, as noted [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#messages-and-immutability) and [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/jmm.html#jmm-shared-state).

Comment: @chunjef I can intuitively see why this is a bad idea, except I need the mutability feature solely in one actor. It is then passed to another actor to be read, no more changes are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to mention that this statement (if it worked) would match any `mutable.Map` due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> [...] To
>   implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>     Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>     therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - [...]
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized
>   types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

To get around that, you can simply create a wrapper class which carries your map:

```
case class MapMessage(map: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[String,Float]])
```

And then in your receive method:

```
def receive = {
    case  MapMessage(x)=>
        insertValueIntoTable(x)
}
```

Regardless of the type you want to pass around it is usually good to have `case class`es as wrapper, and if it is only to give the message a more meaningful name.

Regarding the error, it is hard to tell without more code, but you should get around it with this method anyways.